# create a trajectory for 3D points of different frames Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a vector shown [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y2gfioixz2rt083/XX.mat) which represents the 3d points `X`, `Y` and `Z` of a video `frame1`. I have another vector for 3D points `X`, `Y` and `Z` of a video `frame2`, ... and so on.

Let's say I have 10 frames. I want to track each of the 3D points in `frame1` in the next 9 frames. In other words I want to get the trajectory of each of the 3D points in `frame1` through the next frames as shown in this pic[image: trajectories of 3d points].

If anyone could please advise or guide me how to do this.

Comment: could the people voting to close please explain why this should be closed? As far as I can see this is a perfectly legit question...

Comment: The close votes are on "demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved". E.g. share what was already tried to solve the problem.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: OK, I agree it might seem that way. To the OP: please include a basic script containing what you've tried so far, and your question will be re-opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: those points look like a surface to me...Are you sure you want the trajectories of the individual particles? IMHO, animating the interpolated surfaces through your points will be the better option here, but I could be wrong.

Now, there's a few ways to do what you want. First is using the [`movie`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/movie.html) command, in combination with `getframe`. Suppose you have a cell-array called `frames`, with

```
frames{1} = XX;
```

the data you've linked to, and `frames{2}` through `frames{N}` the data for the remaining `N` frames. Then

```
% This could take a while....
figure(1);
set(gca, 'NextPlot', 'ReplaceChildren');
for ii = 1:N      
    pts = frames{ii};
    plot3(pts(:,1), pts(:,2), pts(:,3), 'r.');    
    F(ii) = getframe;  
end

% Then playback the movie 100 times
movie(F, 100)
```

If you don't want a moving picture, but a static, multi-color plot of the trajectories of all your points, you could do it all in one call to `plot3`. An example for 2 frames:

```
YY = XX;
YY(:,1) = YY(:,1) + 10*rand(size(YY(:,1)))-5;
YY(:,2) = YY(:,2) - 2*rand(size(YY(:,2)))+1;

plot3([XX(:,1) YY(:,1)].', [XX(:,2) YY(:,2)].', [XX(:,3) YY(:,3)].')
```

WARNING: this could take *ages* and will look completely unintelligible for more than say, 20 points (which is why I would animate the interpolated surfaces through the points, and use `surf` to make the frames :)

Another option is using `comet3`, which traces out a given trajectory. Type `doc comet3` in the MATLAB command window for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just don't know how to the same point in the next frame. Lets say `P1 (x1,y1,z1)` is a 3d point in `frame1`, how to know its position in `frame2`? As I want to create the trajectory for every 3D point through a number of frames

Comment: @user1460166: OK, seems you have to explain a bit more. I was under the impression `frame1` and `frame2` contained just as many points, so that `frame1(1,:)` gives the coordinates of the same point as `frame2(1,:)`, just at different times. You are saying this isn't the case?

Comment: Lets say that the depth video captures my hand waving.So I'll assume that the whole thumb will be represented in a pixel Pi1 in frame1 the thumb finger in in position Pos1. What I want to know is how I'm gonna say that the thumb moved to pos2 in frame2?So,what I mean is I want to know the location of the moving object in the frame with the next frames. So, in the waving hand example,if there are 100 3d points or pixels representing the hand in frame1,I want to know the corresponding pixels of these points in the next frames cause the hand is moving,and this is the trajectories I want to create

Comment: I've updated the question and added a figure explaining what I want to do, so if you could please check it. Many Thanks

Comment: any updates on checking how can I do this please? thanks